# What does it mean that one day would be like one year during Dajjal's reign?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, eschatology, dajjal, end-times

I have read the complete story of how Dajjal would come and rule over the whole world except for mecca and medina

It is also mentioned that these 40 days would be different then other days because the one day would be like one year, next one would be like one month, next one would be like one week and remaining 37 days would be normal days.

As it is mentioned that one day from 40 days would be like one year, **does it mean that the whole day from morning to night will complete in one year?**

Comment: theory of relativity...... Suspense, wait and watch.

Answer (score 1):

There are different interpretations for that Hadith.

### Warning: Below are just Interpretation/personal opinion of the Mulana

The only I really like is by `Sheikh Imran N. Hosein`

He says that the first three days that are mentioned are metaphorical. 
He further explains that the first day means the British Rule perhaps starting in 13th century till they lost their power somewhere in the 20th century.

Second day that's equal to one month means the American Rule starting right after the fall of the Great British Empire till they too will fall somewhere soon into the future.

Third day that is equal to a week means the day America falls and a new super power rises, most probably Israel.

After the rise and fall of this new super power, Dajal will appear in physical form and be killed by Prophet Isa peace be upon him.

For Reference: [Dajjal - The False Messiah by Sheikh Imran Hosein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHq4nsYqNcA)

Comment: I've heard that several times and I tend to disagree, _pax Britannica_ was about 100 years long (1815-1914), _pax Americana_ is already 70 years (1945-2015). I don't see the month/year relation here.

Comment: May be he got the timing wrong. But British Empire wasn't just 100 years. If you look at the history, their rule began way before that. Somewhere in the 14th century.. P.S. Its just an opinion based argument. So could be wrong or very wrong.

Comment: Sure British rule started way back but the _hegemony_ matured in 19th century. For one, British rule in subcontinent didn't crystallize until late 18th century, so how could they be the "Great Empire?" In fact, the treaty of Westphalia was in 1648 and until then the Europeans were rather fighting internally. European colonialism began after Westfalia.

Comment: I don't think America really showed its true colors till the fall of Soviet Union. Only after Soviet Union fell did America come out in to the open, somewhere in the early 90s. (1990s) But no point arguing Mulana's interpretation and trying to justify it since the 'Argument' is totally 'opinion-based'.

Comment: If you take the days metaphorically then you need to consider taking dajjal appearance metaphorically as well. It doesn't have to be a giant person with one blind eye. Especially if we do some research its clear the Dajjal's donkey is more like modern day inventions such as aeroplance and ships. More discussed in my question here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31411/what-is-dajjals-donkey-and-its-actual-meaning/31424#31424 Please shed some light if you can.

Answer (score 0):

There are places on this earth where the sun doesn't set for maybe 40 days.
In that same hadith, the Messenger, peace be upon him, explains how to calculate the time for salat (and subsequently fasting Ramadan).

But how did he know all this? It was not known among humans especially in that part of the world.

Answer (score -2):

According to Hadees of prophet as narrated by Sheijh Imran Hosein

Dajjal was given 40 days rule from Allah, where 
1 day will be like a heavenly year (1000 earlthy years) 
1 day will be like a heavenly month (1000/12=82.5 years)
1 day will be like a heavenly week (82.5/4= 21 years) 
And the rest of the days will be like earthly days.

We believe that Dajjal cannot start his rule until there is a rahbar(guider) physically present on earth.

If you follow the family of prophets who were the religious successors (not political) they were known as Imams and there are 12 of them.

The final imam with the name Mahdi went into occulation in 
948 AD

Considering Dajjal was released then, let's calculate 
Now 1 day like 1 heavenly year started

1 heavenly year = 1000 earth years 
So from 948-1948 if you see Britain gained and became the super power on earth. 
He started his rule from there

Suddenly between 1930-1948 Britain started weaking and US became a super power with introduction of Atom bomb

So he shifted his rule from UK to US SLOWLY

1948 se 1 day like 1 heavenly month started

1 hm = 83 years

So 1948 - 2031 period US would be a super power. Next he needs to make a move into Jerusalem...

You will notice that in the early 2000s suddenly Israel became a super power and started fighting Palestine for Jerusalem.

So my belief is that between 2021 - 2031 rule of 1 day like a week rule will start.

1 heavenly week = 21 years

Meaning 
2021-2041 or 2031-2041 Israel will dominate the world and it will become the super power and after that period he will come down to appear visually and continue the rest of the days as earthly days.

Why emphasize so much on Jerusalem is due to the fact that everyone knows Jesus is the true messiah and will have a rule established from Jerusalem. But the name Dajjal means "Deciever" and he will claim to be the false messiah. Any guess how he can make the world believe that he is the true messiah?

When the world is in crisis he will come to Jersusalem and perform magic claiming to be the true messiah. He will restore lands that have withered, provide water and every other possible tricks to deceive true believers. He will even have the power to bring back people to life but the issue is that he can bring back a person to life only once not multiple times. That's where we can identify him.

After this, the arrival of Mahdi and the true Messiah will occur and a war will occur post which peace will be restored until Day of Judgement.

Comment: After British decline, it was NOT the US that became superpower; it was Soviet Union. America did not truly become a superpower until 1989 when the Soviet Union collapsed.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to contribute with following
In Sheikh Imran Hosein book: "Surah al-Kahf and the modern age" chapter 1, page 23 the very same question has been asked and the answer lies in time being multi-dimensional.

I would strongly encourage you to read the book, it can be freely download.

Note I agree to a large extend with the two answers from @user14305 and  @abul abbas

Answer (score -2):

Most got it wrong. The reference to one day like a year, a month, a week, a human day denotes the relative closeness of humanity to Dajjal. It indicates fastness of life. At the time of the Prophet sas, the day was like a year when people used cattle as land vehicle. During the time of the Prophet Sa’s itself, the day of Dajjal turned out to be a month. The people used sail boats and sea routes to reach out to Dajjal. See that Tamil Al Dhari took one month to be tossed ashore the island of Dajjal. The Hadith says Dajjal will fly by the donkey with stretched ears. As people started using Dajjal’s airborne vehicle, the airplane people became closer to Dajjal his week running fast as a day. We are now travelling as fast as the vehicle of Dajjal where our day is no longer than that of the Dajjal.We are using devices connected by satellite technology which makes Allah’s day and night disappear in front of Dajjal’s day and night without a difference between them. The Hadith says he will hear, speak, and see the other side of the earth, sitting from one end.
Sooner, a time will come which will nullify the need of travel. Every thing will be provided in no time and in no change of space. This is the pinnacle of glory of artificial intelligence. The Robot of utmost excellence programmed through satellite devoid of human intervention will be Dajjal of infinite powers and capabilities only Isah a.s will be able to tackle. His (a.s) khilafah will be established by AC 2100, according to my reading.
The earlier Muslims who led a slow pace life far removed from the clutches of Dajjal belong to Sabiqoon. The Muslim here rides on the buraq of Ruh.  None will earn Jannah by his merit when Dajjal reigns. Every one rides on the vehicle of the Dajjal.
Salim Ahamed Kannu

Answer (score -4):

Considering the hadits, a British Jewish activist best known for organizing the departure of Jewish to Israel, David Littman, puts the total figure of emigrants to Israel in 1948–1978 at 70,000. Please check: Littman, David (1979). Jews under Muslim Rule, The Case of Persia. The Wiener Library Bulletin Vol. XXXII, New Series Nos. 49/50. London, U.K.: Institute of Contemporary History (The Wiener Library Limited). p. 5.

Sahih Muslim 2944
Anas b. Malik reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:

The Dajjal would be followed by seventy thousand Jews of Isfahan wearing Persian shawls.

According to this hadith of 70k Jews did isfahan, there is only 9k Jews in that region at the moment...

I like that you guys post about sheikh Imran hossein and he is entitled to his own opinion, but if we look at the ulema of the past and the work they did for the religion, to take in what sheikh Imran has to say is going against majority of the past scholars who never gave their own opinion but based their opinion on other ulemas opinions!!

Also brothers it is proven by science as the moon distances itself from the earth, it creates the days to be longer and as it comes closer to the earth the days begin to move faster...

Allah knows best, but all these miracles the prophet salallahu allayhi wasalam spoke about are being proven by science, for example the string theory, which can create the earth to change the way it spins in which count the sun shall rise from the opposite direction...

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. As is written this hardly addresses the question asked. See [answer].