# What is dajjals donkey and its actual meaning

Tags: dajjal

As mentioned in different hadiths description of Dajjal's donkey I don't have all the references but one of them is as follows from Kanzul-Ummal,vol. Vll, p. 267

> The Dadjjal`s donkey will travel on water as on land. Traveling on
>   land it will have clouds both in front and behind

Also mentioned in other places that the dajjal's donkey will be so big that it will have a large gap between his ears and have opening on sides and people will sit in it. And it will eat fire and it won't burn people sitting in it. It will have comfortable places inside and lighted from within, and people will travel in it. And the donkey will belong to dajjal. And the donkey will be so tall that his head will be beyond the cloud lines. And also mentioned that it will stop at different stages and make announcements.

By travel on water can this be associated to ships.

According to above description can one take the meaning of donkey as an aeroplane. As Plane has jet engine which emit fires and people sit inside it and there are announcements made before it takes off and it travels above the cloud lines. 
It makes more sense when taken metaphorically and if taken literally it doesn't seem possible for such a huge donkey to exist and doesn't even make any sense. Seems more like a fiction story.

Is this concept valid and if not then what are the obstacles behind it.

The link from where I have taken the concept from is below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZqqm-M7HBA

Comment: Do you have the Arabic of the Hadith?

Comment: I don't have arabic, i'm trying to get one.

Comment: I've never heard of any Saheeh Hadeeths that deal in such details about Dajjal's means of transport. You have to check the isnad on this description, since the book you reference is not exclusive to only verified authentic narrations.

Comment: In this matter it doesn't seem like we need authentication as the results of those prophecies in itself are proof of authentication of those hadiths. I'll find exact hadiths and will post here.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum ve Rahmatullah.

Brother I have read a part from Risala e Noor. It is a tafseer of quran.  In the Rays book. In the 5th Ray Said Nursi makes te'vil of the qiyamah hadiths. I advice you to read all of the 5th ray. But here to make an example, he says:

> In the Name of God, the Merciful, the Compassionate.
>     A point about the verse,
>
> But already have come some tokens thereof {[*]: Qur'an, 47:18.}
>
> was written in order to protect the belief of the mass of believers and preserve it from doubt. Like allegorical verses of the Qur'an, some Hadiths about the events of the end of time have profound meanings. They cannot be expounded in the same way as incontestable verses, and not everyone can understand them. Rather than being expounded, they are interpreted. According to the verse,
>
> But none save God knows its final meaning (ta'wil). And those who are deeply rooted in knowledge, {[*]: Qur'an, 3:7.} 
>   their meaning, interpretation and what is intended by them is understood only after the event, so that those firmly grounded in knowledge say:
>     "We believe in it; the whole [of the divine writ] is from our Sustainer, {[*]: Qur'an, 3:7.} and they disclose those hidden truths.
>
> Also, since the wonders of both the Antichrists (Dajjal), which are related to their centuries, have been narrated in connection with them, those wonders have been imagined to proceed from their persons and this has led to the narrations becoming allegorical and their true meanings being concealed. Like, for example, his travelling by aeroplane and railway train.
>      And, for example, it is well-known that when the Islamic Antichrist dies, the satan who serves him will shout out the news to the whole world {[*]: Muslim, Fitan, 34.} from 'Dikili Tas,' the obelisk in Istanbul, and everyone will hear its voice saying that he is dead. That is to say, the news will be broadcast by radio, which is wonderful and leaves even satans in amazement.
>      Also, since the strange circumstances and fearsome activities of the Antichrist's regime, and the covert organization and government that he founds, have been narrated as referring to his person, their true meaning has remained obscure.
>   The Rays - 100

To sum up it may seem a fiction story but the meaning behind is understood with ta'wil. That kind of hadiths needs ta'wil. So you should not take its exterior meaning. The donkey can be aeroplane or train. So it does not need to be literally a donkey.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a fightherjet since the frontal guns will spew gunsmoke, as the jet engines will emit smoke.

They can travel on the sea with carriers, so the prophecy are literal and fulfilled.

Answer (score -4):

All forms of modern transportation are destructive to the earth - Allah's creation and blessing to human beings. If we continue to rely on aeroplanes, cars etc we are rejecting God and embracing Dajjal the price of human arrogance will be costly - famine, war, drought, fire. Anyone who truly loves God should refuse all the destructive modes of modern transportation the dajjal has forced upon humanity.

Comment: Go to Makkah by feet then.